# How to know what files to #include in a Nios II application?

Tags: eclipse, nios-ii

In the hello world application created by the Nios II Eclipse IDE, it put in the #include "sys/alt_stdio.h". I am not sure why it is not just stdio.h and where does sys/ come from.

In any case, as I add PIO and other peripherals to my design, how do I know what files to #include into my design?

For example, I added a PIO and then writing IORD(BTN_BASE,0); did not work. My trial and error I found that I have to #include "system.h". I am surprised that the IDE does not already do that. Then I still had error message saying that the function IORD is not recognzied. Then via internet search I found that I have to #include "io.h".

Where is all this detail documented?

Comment: That's the price to pay for using a full IDE I guess. You never know where the things are, what is generated and what you are supposed to modify yourself, and so on. I used the Nios II quite a bit, and I do not remember any documentation. Try to create a blank project, and explore the folder where it is saved: many files will be there, while some others are in the program directory. The compiler searches for .h files in the places you tell it (buried in the settings): start from there too. Good luck!

Comment: I am blown away by the number if files generated by in the BSP and the application template. Making me wonder, why would one need all that for an application. It looks almost unreal.